# Given the GPU info, what is the highest version of DirectX and OpenGL supported?

Tags: c#, opengl, directx, gpu

In my C# program, I get all information about the GPU installed via WMI. Now, I need to know what is the highest version of OpenGL and DirectX supported by this GPU.

How can I do it in C# using .NET 3.5?

Comment: For OpenGL, you ask OpenGL, not WMI (create a context, query the maximum version).

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Ben. But how do I ask OpenGL? Do I have to use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com) or is there another lighter C# DLL that can be used just to retrieve this info?

Comment: You can p/invoke opengl32.dll.  Calling `SetPixelFormat`, `wglCreateContext`, and `glGetInteger`  See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Get_Context_Info  And http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421810/103167 and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/28451

Comment: Your question is more vague than you probably realize. Direct3D version support means different things to different people. Do you mean the most recent version of Direct3D that can support the hardware? Or the most recent version of Direct3D that can support the latest driver for that hardware? Or what is the latest version Direct3D is supported by the driver on the current machine? Or what version of Direct3D best corresponds to the set of capabilities that the hardware (or driver) supports?

Comment: I mean the most recent version of Direct3D that can support the hardware.